# How to get dependencies of classes, voids, etc from java source code?

Tags: java, netbeans, architecture

is there some way how to get all dependencies of java objects of my custom application?
By Dependency I mean inheritance or that some void is calling another void. Or when some code in one "capsule" needs another "capsule"(Class, void etc.) in constructor.

Example output:
ClassA depends ClassB.voidA;
ClassA.voidA is dependent ClassC.voidB

etc. I am using netBeans platform.

Thank you for replies.

Comment: What do you mean by "dependencies"? Does a method A "depend" on method B for its execution if A calls B? Or does a method A "depend" on a method with the same name in a parent class?

Comment: I updated question so I hope that help to understand

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/. Based on the sample screenshot I think this is what you need.